# How to change Admin Url path

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I am using magento version 1.8.1. and I want to change admin url path.

Is there any possibility to change admin url path with two slashes after domain name?

I want to like http://test.com/test/admin ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: what you have tried so far...?

Comment: I have followed these 2 methods but its not working for me. its only support one name after domain name. url : http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-change-admin-url-path/

Comment: Is your install in a sub folder of the main domain?

Comment: https://www.properhost.com/members/knowledgebase/15/How-to-change-the-Magento-Admin-URL-or-Path.html please check this `note` special character is not allowed in this. make sure you are not using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the route for admin to test from local.xml,
 but as magento request flow takes second param as controller name, it will go searching for `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/AdminContoller` , which will throw 404

Instead you can try to make it test_admin..

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

app\etc\local.xml

```
<frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
```

or alias in server or alias in htacess